# Percorrer inputs com o mesmo name e pegar todos os values

Tags: delphi-7

Tenho uma aplicação web na qual eu passo por `input hidden` um número dinâmico de `values` através
de um formulário para uma `action` do Delphi.

Na `action`, eu queria saber uma forma de pegar todos os `values` com o mesmo name.

Quando é um só `value`, eu uso `request.ContentFields.Values['numero']`

Estou passando os inputs do formulário da seguinte forma:

```
<input type="hidden" name="numero[]" value="123" />
<input type="hidden" name="numero[]" value="456" />
<input type="hidden" name="numero[]" value="789" />
```

Mas como eu pego todos dentro da `action`?

- Da forma convencional retorna apenas o conteúdo do primeiro `input`.
- Tentei criar um array dinâmico e passar para ele, mas não deu certo.

Comment: Está utilizando intraweb?

Comment: não Tiago. Aqui fazemos jogando o html dentro de um response.content

Comment: ok, interessante. Se souber algum link na web sobre uma aplicação parecida com o que vocês fazem eu ficaria contente de poder ver, pois gostaria de conhecer. Grato!

Comment: Mas a propósito, as propriedades **name** estão com o valor **numero[]**. você está jogando um índice nesses nomes, certo? Para que fique.. `numero[0], numero[1], numero[2]` e então receber por um vetor..

Comment: Tiago. O que eu queria era assar todos com o mesmo name e percorrer todos esses na action e pegar os valores. Como não estou conseguindo descobrir como fazer isso no delphi 7, estou passando para essa solução que você perguntou. Passarei vários inputs com names diferentes. Assim conseguirei pegar do outro lado tranquilamente.

Answer (score 1):

Vamos lá, eu não sei como é isso que você está fazendo pelo Delphi, então vou utilizar uma abordagem que temos no C#.

Se você tem algo dessa forma:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="numero[0]" value="123" />
<input type="hidden" name="numero[1]" value="456" />
<input type="hidden" name="numero[2]" value="789" />
```

Depois você teria algo mais ou menos assim no delphi:

```delphi
type
  TIntegerArray: Array of Integer;

procedure TMinhaClass.MinhaAction(numero: TIntegerArray);
var
  I: integer;
begin
  // podendo então:
  for I := 0 to High(numero) do
  begin
     // fazer o que deseja com "numero[I]".
  end;
end;
```

Essa resposta é totalmente baseada em especulação.
Outro ponto é que os campos precisam ter sempre uma ordem, sem quebras, pois algo como:

```
numero[0]
numero[1]
numero[3]
```

Algo assim você receberia apenas os valores com índice 0 e 1 em sua `action`, o campo com índice 3 não receberia por conta da quebra.
Confirme isso também.

Comment: Entendi a sua abordagem. Mas o que eu tenho são com names iguais mesmo. Já estou desistindo e passando com names diferentes mesmo. Assim fica simples pega toso os valores com um for.